# Integration of $\int \frac{(1 + x)\sin x}{(x^2 +2 x)\cos^2 x-(1 + x)\sin2x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

The integral is $$\int \dfrac{(1 + x)\sin x}{(x^2 + 2x)\cos^2 x-(1 + x)\sin2x}dx.$$I've tried the problem by first multiplying both the numerator and denominator by $\sec^2 x$ but couldn't do justice. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Do not use \dfrac or \displaystyle or any other sort of displaystyles in the title in the future.

Comment: @Zain Patel: Ok, sir.

Comment: Hm, just for note: derivative of $x^2+2x$ is $2(1+x)$ and derivative for $\cos^2 x$ is $-\sin 2x$.

Comment: Where did you get the problem from? Why do you think it's reasonable to expect a closed form? These questions are highly relevant to answering questions like these.

Comment: i don't think that this integral has a solution in the known elementary functions

Comment: Answer: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=%28%281%2Bx%29sinx%29%2F%28%28x%5E2%2B2x%29%28cosx%29%5E2-%281%2Bx%29sin2x%29&random=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{(1+x)\sin x}{(x^2+2x)\cos^2 x-(1+x)\sin 2x}dx$$

$$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{(1+x)\sin x}{(x^2+2x+1)\cos^2 x-(1+x)\sin 2x-\cos^2 x}dx$$

$$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{(1+x)\sin x}{\left[(x+1)\cos x\right]^2-2(x+2)\sin x\cdot \cos x-(1-\sin^2 x)}dx$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{(1+x)\sin x}{\left[(x+1)\cos x\right]^2-2(x+1)\sin x\cdot \cos x+\sin^2 x-1}dx$$

$$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{(1+x)\sin x}{\left[(x+1)\cos x-\sin x\right]^2-1^2}dx$$

Now Let $(x+1)\cos x-\sin x = t\;,$ Then $(x+1)\sin xdx = -dt$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = -\int\frac{1}{t^2-1}dt = -\frac{1}{2}\int\left[\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{t+1}\right]dt$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{2}\left[\ln|t+1|-\ln|t-1|\right]+\mathcal{C} = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right|+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{2}\ln \left|\frac{(x+1)\cos x-\sin x+1}{(x+1)\cos x-\sin x-1}\right|+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: How did you grab it? What should be my approach to such problems?

Answer (score 1):

It might help to factorize the denominator and do partial fraction this way

Denominator$=(x^2+2x+1)\cos^2(x)-(1+x)\sin2x-\cos^2x\\=\cos^2x[(x+1)^2-2(x+1)\tan(x)-1]\\=\cos^2x(x+1-(\tan(x)+\sec(x)))(x+1-(\tan(x)-\sec(x)))$

The answer without process can be found using http://www.wolframalpha.com, which involves lots of natural log function, which is why I think partial fraction is the way to do.